# How to access public class member called 'properties'?

Tags: groovy

Suppose I have the following Java-class from 3rd party library:

```
public class Itm {
    public final Map<String, String> properties = ['foo': 'bar']
}
```

With the following code `println new Itm().properties` I expect to get a Map: `[[foo:bar]]`

But the result is:

> [class:class Itm]

I realized that if I create the same class in Groovy, but declare `properties` field without `public` modifier, I get an expected result. But the class I work with has `public` access modifier. So in this case how can I access `public` field called `properties`, not default Groovy's `getProperties(Object self)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Groovy's [direct field access operator `obj.@field`](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_direct_field_access_operator). This operator omits using the getter method and accesses the object field directly. Let's say we have the following Java class:

*Itm.java*

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Itm {
    public final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String,String>() {{
        put("foo", "bar");
    }};


}
```

And the following Groovy script that uses it:

```
println new Itm().@properties
```

The output is:

```
[foo:bar]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why omitting `public` keyword also helps?

Comment: It worked without `public` keyword in Groovy class, because `final Map properties` gets compiled to a final private field with overriden `public Map getProperties()` method. So when you called `new Itm().properties` you invoked this getter method that returns a properties field instead of default Groovy `getProperties` method.